# Python3 pass parameter of internal helper function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way I can do the following other than moving the helper functions outside of `bar` or passing in a string for `FUNC_TO_CALL` and then selecting a function based on the string?

```
#foo.py
def bar(FUNC_TO_CALL)
   def helper_function_1():
       ...
   def helper_function_2():
       ...

   FUNC_TO_CALL()

#main.py
foo.bar(bar.helper_function_1) #<- HOW DO I PASS IN THIS HELPER INTERNAL TO BAR AS ARGUMENT?
```

I have a function `bar` with a lot of helpers that I want to call with a parameter passed to `bar`. The alternative would be to move all the helpers to the module level but this is messy because they are useless outside of `bar`.

Comment: Does your function `bar` do anything other than calling the wanted function?

Comment: Yes it does other things.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to study the possibilities of making a decorator out of `bar`:

```
def bar(helper):
    def process():
        print('preprocessing...')
        # Anything you need to do prior to calling the helper function
        helper()

    return process

@bar
def helper_function_1():
    print('helper 1')

@bar
def helper_function_2():
    print('helper 2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    helper_function_1()
    helper_function_2()
```

This gives the output:

```
preprocessing...
helper 1
preprocessing...
helper 2
```

Though if the helper functions are just a little part of `bar`'s job, it doesn't make much sense.